# how to show Container View ViewController and hide Container view ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicontainerview

[I want to show ContainerView's view controller as like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRNtu.png)

I use the following Code and it shows as i want

```
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.8];
if (_addLinkQuestionView.isHidden == YES)
{
    _addLinkQuestionView.hidden = NO;
    _addLinkQuestionView.alpha = 1.0;
}
else
{
    _addLinkQuestionView.alpha = 0.0;
    _addLinkQuestionView.hidden = YES;
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but Upon a click on blurr area, i want to hide container view. that area is the UIButton. I use the following code, but it does nothing.

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.8];
    _addLinkQuestionView.alpha = 0.0;
    _addLinkQuestionView.hidden = YES;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Any Help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: What do u have for the container? a UIViewController instance or a xib with .h and .m?

Comment: Please make sure, that the second code portion is executing while tapping the blur area by putting a breakpoint or a `NSLog`

Comment: Basically, what u want is to dismiss the popup with animation upon tapping the background right?

Comment: Consider to use custom ViewController Transition before that you need to create new view controller. Here is good tutorial how to handle this https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Comment: container have a UIViewController instance

Comment: yes my breakpoint show that program goes into second code

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it seems you need to show a alertview behaviour where all the ui from app is disabled while only the content in the dialog is enabled.

- Add a public method like showOverlayView:(UIView*)v to your app delegate
- On this method create a view, set alpha and add it to keywindow.
- Now add the passed view to keywindow and calculate and set
  its center property.

Alternatively you could use a library like [MJPopupViewController](https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController) or [SLPopupViewController](https://github.com/sunlight3d/SLPopupViewController) to do the job for you.

Comment: This image has the requirement you gave https://camo.githubusercontent.com/02c924c29bfaed3a0b54f64438d59adb8e166d68/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f6d617274696e6a756861737a2f4d4a506f70757056696577436f6e74726f6c6c65722f6d61737465722f6173736574732f64656d6f322e706e67

MJPopupViewController is the library to use.

Or add the tapGestureRecognizer on your container view to achieve same.

Comment: Yes. Exactly as u show, but without 3rd party integration.

Comment: ok do not use third party. assume you stored the container in a variable container. somewhere in your VC load function write

UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

then declare a function like this
-(void)handleTap
{
     [container removeFromSuperView];
}

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this :

1- New File -> UIView -> rename it to addLinkQuestionView

2- New File -> obj c class -> rename it to addLinkQuestionView

Now u have a xib,a .h and a .m

3- Go to the xib and in file's owner select your addLinkQuestionView u created in step 2

4- Design the xib as the picture link you posted and link up appropriate outlets to addLinkQuestionView.h

5- For initialization of your uiview in .h do this :
    #import "addLinkQuestionView.h"

```
@implementation addLinkQuestionView

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during     animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code
}
*/

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    // Initialization code.
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"addLinkQuestionView" owner:self options:nil];


    self.vuComplete.frame = CGRectMake(self.vuComplete.frame.origin.x, self.vuComplete.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    [self addSubview:self.vuComplete];

    self.vuContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    self.vuContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    self.vuContainer.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
    self.vuContainer.alpha = 0.0;


    [self layoutIfNeeded];

}
return self;
}
 -(void)awakeFromNib
{


}



- (IBAction)onBackgroundTapDismissView:(id)sender {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{self.vuContainer.alpha = 0.0;}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){  }];

[self removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Note : - (IBAction)onBackgroundTapDismissView can be a accomplished by dropping  a uitapgesturerecognizer on your addLinkQuestionView's greyed background uiview so that tapping it can dismiss the entire uiview (vuComplete)

6- Then add this in your main view controller that is presenting this pop up like this :
 A- import addLinkQuestionView.h first
 B- add this code on your button action that you're clicking for presenting addLinkQuestionView:
     addLinkQuestionView *popup = [[addLinkQuestionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                         animations:^{popup. addLinkQuestionView.alpha = 1.0;}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){  }];
        [self.view addSubview:popup];
```

Have fun!

Comment: How to do this With ViewController instead of xib. I already designed the view Controller for the container which is shown in the pic.

Comment: use presentViewController function with animation